# Angular 2 - Karma coverage reporter misses statements inside fakeAsync() calls

Tags: angular, karma-runner

My coverage reporter fails to detect statements used if they are put inside a fakeAsync() during testing:

```typescipt
describe('countWords', () => {
  it('should total number of words in string; should be 2 for "butt heaven" ', () => {
    expect(comp.countWords('butt heaven')).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

Will be detected fine but....

```typescipt
describe('countWords', () => {
  it('should total number of words in string; should be 2 for "butt heaven" ', () => {
      fakeAsync( () => {
        expect(comp.countWords('butt heaven')).toBe(2);
      });
  });
});
```

Will cause karma to report

> statement not covered and lower coverage percentage.

How can I solve this?

Comment: @yurzui that solved it, thanks, feel free to submit that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've mistyped. The correct syntax should be:

```typescript
it('Some description', fakeAsync(() => {
   expect(comp.countWords('butt heaven')).toBe(2);
}));
```